# Eclipse "JPA Entities from Tables" how to map mysql datatypes to java datatypes?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipse-kepler

I have eclipse kepler (really jbdev studio 7 alpha).  The JPA Entities from Tables feature is amazing!  Very sophisticated.  Start it up with right-clicking on a project to which the JPA facet has been added.  Then "New->JPA Entities from Tables" and follow the wizard.

There are lots of ways to customize the mapping of tables to entities, including lots of flexibility regarding relations between tables, but one thing I can not find is how to map database datatypes to java datatypes.

The result is that my entities were generated with many primitive datatypes and it's causing me problems.

How to do a "JPA Entities from Tables" and tell the generator to map MySQL "int" to Java "Integer" and not java "int"?

Big pain if I have to go in and edit these manually. :-(  There are many attributes in many classes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.